# How to migrate from Cloud Formation to Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We have decided to migrate from AWS Cloud Formation to Terraform because:

1. Cloud Formation does not seem to work well with nested functions.
2. Cloud Formation takes quite a bit of time to rollout complex projects. In our case sometimes up to 10 minutes.
3. Cloud Formation may stop with unclear reason (which will be difficult to get from logs).

Questions that we have are:

1. Is there any recommended path/procedure/strategy for this migration?
2. What are the long term disadvantages of using Terraform comparing to AWS Cloud Formation?
   Thank you

Comment: Of the items that you're trying to solve, imo (extensive experience with both), Terraform only solves #1.

Comment: 1. Someone with experience in each, especially in TF module arch, does a brownfield conversion with best practices refactoring. 2. A custom resource in CF is easier than in a TF provider.

Comment: As for 2. one disadvantage is that sometimes Terreform lags behind when it comes to new features or integrations, for example SNS to FireHose integration (AFAIK in GA from Jan 2021) is not yet supported.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [github](https://github.com/ulich/cloudformation-to-terraform-migration) you can migrate AWS cloud formation resources to Terraform following step by step process.